# Uploading multiple files with documents

Tags: javascript, post, mongoose, response, multer

I want to add multiple files with documents and it works, but I have multiple errors and all things are seen after reloading page.
Here's my post route:

```
// @route POST /upload
// @desc  Uploads file and object to DB
router.post('/', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  if (req.files !== undefined) {
    console.log(req.files);
    req.files.map(({ id, filename }) => {
      const newGallery = new Gallery({
        files_id: id,
        image: '/api/gallery/image/' + filename,
        description: req.body.description,
        tripLocation: req.body.tripLocation,
      })
      newGallery.save().then(photo => res.json(photo))
    });
  }
});
```

And here's the warning/error(I get X errors, if I upload X files, and this rejection id:x is the order number of file):

> (node:7855) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
>   [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the
>   client [0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
>   [0]     at ServerResponse.header
>   (/home/wiktor/MyApp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
>   [0]     at ServerResponse.send
>   (/home/wiktor/MyApp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
>   [0]     at ServerResponse.json
>   (/home/wiktor/MyApp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
>   [0]     at newGallery.save.then.photo
>   (/home/wiktor/MyApp/routes/api/gallery.js:94:43) [0]     at
>   process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) [0]
>   (node:7855) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)

And I suspect that problem is probably connected with that res.json(), which from what I studied should be used only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
// @route POST /upload
// @desc  Uploads file and object to DB
router.post('/', upload.any(), async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.files !== undefined) {
    console.log(req.files);
    await Promise.all(req.files.map(({ id, filename }) => {
      const newGallery = new Gallery({
        files_id: id,
        image: '/api/gallery/image/' + filename,
        description: req.body.description,
        tripLocation: req.body.tripLocation,
      })
      return newGallery.save()
    })).then(data => res.json(data))
       .catch(err => next(err))
  }
});
```